# How to properly pass a single event from one widget to another?

Tags: flutter

I have two custom widgets:

1. An output field to display an amount of money
2. A digital keyboard with number keys to enter an amount

[The layout image is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bubQ.png)

When a user taps on a number key of the keyboard widget, I want this number to be added to the output field widget. It's just a one-time event for the keyboard and the parent widgets. The pressed number should be added only to the state of the output field's widget, not the parent's widget.

How do I do that properly?

I've implemented this making the output's widget State class public with a public method "onKeyPressed". Then, I use a GlobalKey to make a direct call to that public method when a number on the keyboard is pressed. But this solution seems awkward and going against the UI architecture.

Comment: so you need some kind of controller for the first output widget - something what `TextEditingController` is for `TextField` - but honestly why not to pass the value as a widget parameter? just like ordinary `Text` widget is working

Comment: will you create a format money in your flutter app?

Comment: @pskink the output field has some customisable logic that handles key presses - like limiting the max length of the string, etc. So I can't just pass it the value. At first glance, the controller looks like the right thing to use, I'll try it. Thanks!